# Creating a KQL function to calculate the working hours between two given times

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Given that I can't find a built in function for this I want to create a user-defined function to create the working hours between two given datetimes based on an assumed M-F working schedule and a given start end shift time of 9:00 and 17:00.
I've also provided a basic mechanism to discount public holidays.
UPDATE: See latest version of code block  at the bottom of the post. I've kept the original to tie in with the suggestions I've had so far.

```
let workingTime = (startTime:datetime, endTime:datetime, workdayStart:datetime, workdayEnd:datetime) 
{ 
// calculate number of full working days between start and end
//declare public holidays
let holidays = datatable(Holidays: datetime)
    [
    datetime(2022-04-15),datetime(2023-04-07),datetime(2023-05-01),datetime(2023-12-25)];
let middle_days = range Date from datetime_add('day', 1, startofday(startTime)) to datetime_add('day', -1, startofday(endTime)) step 1d;
let middle_work_days = toscalar(middle_days
    | where dayofweek(Date) / 1d between (1..5)
    | where Date !in (holidays)
    | summarize count());
let table = 
    union (print workdayStart=workdayStart, workdayEnd=workdayEnd, startTime=startTime, endTime=endTime, middle_work_days=middle_work_days);
table
| extend workday_start_dt = make_datetime(0001, 1, 1, hourofday(workdayStart), datetime_part('minute', workdayStart), 0)
| extend workday_end_dt = make_datetime(0001, 1, 1, hourofday(workdayEnd), datetime_part('minute', workdayEnd), 0)
| extend start_time_dt = make_datetime(0001, 1, 1, hourofday(startTime), datetime_part('minute', startTime), 0)
| extend end_time_dt = make_datetime(0001, 1, 1, hourofday(endTime), datetime_part('minute', endTime), 0)
| extend hoursinday = datetime_diff('hour', workday_end_dt, workday_start_dt)
| extend working_duration =  toreal(middle_work_days) * hoursinday
| extend workday_start_hour = datetime_part('hour', workdayStart)
| extend workday_start_min = datetime_part('minute', workdayStart)
| extend workday_end_hour = datetime_part('hour', workdayEnd)
| extend workday_end_min = datetime_part('minute', workdayEnd)
| extend hours_on_last_day = 
    iff(
    ((dayofweek(endTime) / 1d between (1..5)) and 
    startofday(endTime) !in (holidays) and 
    end_time_dt >= workday_start_dt),
    iff(
    end_time_dt >= workday_end_dt,
    toreal(hoursinday),
    //total time passed on the end date
    toreal(datetime_diff('second', endTime, startofday(endTime))) / 60 / 60
    -
    //time between midnight and start of the working day
    toreal(datetime_diff('second', make_datetime(datetime_part('year', endTime), datetime_part('month', endTime), datetime_part('day', endTime), workday_start_hour, workday_start_min), startofday(endTime)) / 60 / 60
    )),
    toreal(0)
    )
| extend hours_on_first_day = 
    iff(
    ((dayofweek(startTime) / 1d between (1..5)) and 
    startofday(startTime) !in (holidays) and 
    start_time_dt < workday_end_dt),
    iff(
    start_time_dt < workday_start_dt,
    toreal(hoursinday),
    toreal(datetime_diff('second', make_datetime(datetime_part('year', startTime), datetime_part('month', startTime), datetime_part('day', startTime), workday_end_hour, workday_end_min), startTime)) / 60 / 60
    ),
    toreal(0)    
    )
| project   total_working_hours = (working_duration + hours_on_first_day + hours_on_last_day)
};
```

When providing some sample data below I'm getting the error "Tabular expression is not expected in the current context".
I was hoping to have an additional column that provided the working duration from the sample start and end dates.
I'm assuming I'm trying to generate a scalar output from a table function, or vice-versa, but I'm getting in a knot trying to produce the expected output.

```
//sample start and end times
let startTime_var = datetime_utc_to_local(datetime("2023-05-05 13:54:00"), 'Europe/London');
let endTime_var = datetime_utc_to_local(datetime("2023-06-09 08:46"), 'Europe/London');
//sample start and end of shift in local time
let workdayStart_var = datetime("09:00");
let workdayEnd_var = datetime("17:00");
//create a sample table based on the sample data
let sampletable = union(print startTime=startTime_var, endTime=endTime_var, workdayStart=workdayStart_var, workdayEnd=workdayEnd_var);
sampletable
| extend workingTime(startTime_var, endTime_var, workdayStart, workdayEnd_var)
```

UPDATE:
I have now edited my original function to be a scalar type. This now works to a point but am running into issues with the toscalar() limitations.

```
let workingTime = (startTime:datetime, endTime:datetime, workdayStart:datetime, workdayEnd:datetime)
{ 
// calculate number of full working days between start and end
//declare public holidays
let holidays = datatable(Holidays: datetime)
    [
    datetime(2022-04-15),datetime(2023-04-07),datetime(2023-05-01),datetime(2023-12-25)];
let middle_days = range Date from datetime_add('day', 1, startofday(startTime)) to datetime_add('day', -1, startofday(endTime)) step 1d;
let middle_work_days = toscalar(middle_days
    | where dayofweek(Date) / 1d between (1..5)
    | where Date !in (holidays)
    | summarize count());
let workday_start_dt = make_datetime(0001, 1, 1, hourofday(workdayStart), datetime_part('minute', workdayStart), 0);
let workday_end_dt = make_datetime(0001, 1, 1, hourofday(workdayEnd), datetime_part('minute', workdayEnd), 0);
let start_time_dt = make_datetime(0001, 1, 1, hourofday(startTime), datetime_part('minute', startTime), 0);
let end_time_dt = make_datetime(0001, 1, 1, hourofday(endTime), datetime_part('minute', endTime), 0);
let hoursinday = datetime_diff('hour', workday_end_dt, workday_start_dt);
let working_duration = toreal(middle_work_days) * hoursinday;
let workday_start_hour = datetime_part('hour', workdayStart);
let workday_start_min = datetime_part('minute', workdayStart);
let workday_end_hour = datetime_part('hour', workdayEnd);
let workday_end_min = datetime_part('minute', workdayEnd);
let hours_on_last_day = 
    iff(
    ((dayofweek(endTime) / 1d between (1..5)) and 
    startofday(endTime) !in (holidays) and 
    end_time_dt >= workday_start_dt),
    iff(
    end_time_dt >= workday_end_dt,
    toreal(hoursinday),
    //total time passed on the end date
    toreal(datetime_diff('second', endTime, startofday(endTime))) / 60 / 60
    -
    //time between midnight and start of the working day
    toreal(datetime_diff('second', make_datetime(datetime_part('year', endTime), datetime_part('month', endTime), datetime_part('day', endTime), workday_start_hour, workday_start_min), startofday(endTime)) / 60 / 60
    )),
    toreal(0)
    );
let hours_on_first_day = 
    iff(
    ((dayofweek(startTime) / 1d between (1..5)) and 
    startofday(startTime) !in (holidays) and 
    start_time_dt < workday_end_dt),
    iff(
    start_time_dt < workday_start_dt,
    toreal(hoursinday),
    toreal(datetime_diff('second', make_datetime(datetime_part('year', startTime), datetime_part('month', startTime), datetime_part('day', startTime), workday_end_hour, workday_end_min), startTime)) / 60 / 60
    ),
    toreal(0)    
    )
;
working_duration + hours_on_first_day + hours_on_last_day
};
```

I believe I need to find another way to calculate the "middle_work_days" variable without using toscalar().

Answer (score 0):

> *I'm assuming I'm trying to generate a scalar output from a table function, or vice-versa, but I'm getting in a knot trying to produce the expected output.*

you can try adjusting your function to accept tabular input, then use the [`invoke` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/invokeoperator).

for example:

```
let MyFunction = (
    T:(
        startTime:datetime,
        endTime:datetime,
        workdayStart:datetime,
        workdayEnd:datetime)
    )
{ 
   < ... your logic goes here ... >
}
;
MyTable // this table has columns with the following names/types: 
        // startTime:datetime, endTime:datetime, workdayStart:datetime, workdayEnd:datetime
| invoke MyFunction()
```

Comment: Thanks.
Unfortunately not. It's now throwing errors with the datatypes, "
'' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'startTime'"

Comment: So I've edited the function to take scalar input.  
If I now call it from extend, as I was hoping to I get errors about the scalar limitation. I can't see how I can perform a join as the document suggests as this is intended to be a calculated field and doesn't share a unique identifier.  
e.g.  
SecurityIncident  
| where Status == 'Closed'  
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated,*) by IncidentName  
| project CreatedTime, ClosedTime  
| take 3  
| extend workingTime(CreatedTime, ClosedTime, workday_start_time, workday_end_time)